# C++ File I/O Works Only When Run In IDE (Visual C++ Express 2010)

Tags: c++, file, io

Code for creating my output file:

```
ofstream outFile;
outFile.open(filename, ios::trunc);
```

When I run the program from my IDE, the output file is created in the project directory, and it all works.

However, when I run the program by actually opening the .exe from release in windows explorer, no file is created, even though

```
outFile.is_open()
```

returns true.

How do I fix this? Or perhaps the file is being created somewhere I don't know? Because I would expect it to show up in the working directory.

Note: I am not using an absolute path for filename, it is being set to things like "out.txt".

EDIT: I have used GetCurrentDirectory, and found out when I just run the .exe from windows explorer it uses My Documents and Settings as the current directory. So now I must ask, how would I get it to use the .exe's directory as the working directory?

Comment: Are you specifying a full path in the filename? You might use a tool  like procmon and see where the file is being created.

Comment: @David W So far I've been setting filename to things like "output.txt".

Comment: If is_open returns true, then I would suspect the file is being created in an unexpected location for presently unknown reasons :). Would still suggest giving procmon a try.

Comment: Where does the program think it is running from?  What does GetCurrentDirectory http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934(v=vs.85).aspx return?

Comment: If by running from visual studio, file is created in working directory then when you execute the file from release directory `out_file` should be created in release directory. Does release directory have write permission? Also can you post more code , specifically the value of **filename** string

Comment: also check user permissions on the directory

Comment: @cup Ok, I found out it is using `Documents and Settings` as the current directory (when I'm not running from VC++). How then would I write to the same directory as the .exe?

Comment: If you know the explicit path to which you want your output file to be written, try SetCurrentDirectory. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @DavidW What I would like now is to set the CD to the application's location.

Comment: Use the code that was posted by @txtechhelp and once you've parsed out the folder name, use it as the argument to SetCurrentDirectory.

Answer (score 1):

To get the current path of the exe file (not the current working directory as what `GetCurrentDirectory` does), you'll need the [`GetModuleFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

It can be used like such:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

const char* module_path()
{
    static char p[FILENAME_MAX];
    memset(&p, 0, FILENAME_MAX);
    GetModuleFileName(0, p, FILENAME_MAX);
    return p;
}

std::string directory_only(const std::string& p)
{
    return p.substr(0, p.find_last_of("/\\"));
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string cpath = module_path();
    std::string new_file = directory_only(cpath) + "\\somefile.txt";
    std::cout << "full exe: " << cpath << std::endl;
    std::cout << "directory: " << directory_only(cpath) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "new_file = " << new_file << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`GetModuleFileName` will get you where the current exe is at, then using some string manipulation you can get the directory of the file.

I hope that helps.